# Finding multi word anagrams from a set of words

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, strings, constraint-satisfaction, constraint-programming

Finding all anagrams for a word $w$ from a set of words is a problem with many well-known solutions (for example make a hash table mapping from the bag of letters of a word to the word).

But what about finding multi-word anagrams?  For example "Eleven plus two" is an anagram of "Twelve plus one".  In other words, given a multi-word phrase $w_1,\dots,w_s$, find a set of $s$ words that form a multi-word anagram.

I've thought about this for a bit and I came up with a $O(n^2)$ algorithm for all 3-word anagrams of a string, where $n$ is the number of words in the dictionary -- it basically comes down to the 3-sum problem but for histograms instead of integers. Are there any better algorithms? Assume the set of words is valid English words and $|s| \le 30$.

Comment: What is you $O(n^2)$ solution?

Comment: Sort by length in $O(n^2 logn)$ then sum in order $O(n^2 logn)$ then anagram in $O(m)$